# SharePoint IP Address Restrictions on Anonymous sharing

Tags: security, sharing, restricted-access

My goal is to restrict access on my web excel documents from outside my organization.

This works fine on all my OneDrive files except the ones I'm sharing anonymously.

For example I have a document on my drive that I'm sharing with a link. Any authorized person with a link can view it until I restrict IP addresses. After that it is no longer accessible  outside the organization

[image: network restrictions]

Now same document, same restrictions, but this time I shared it with "anyone with the link" option

[image: share-with-anyone]

Network restrictions did not affect this type of sharing and I was still able to access it outside specified IP range.

Is there any workaround I can use to still restrict such cases?
So any shared link follows same restrictions put on my access control.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable Anyone links as they're intended to be uncontrolled. Note that when you disable Anyone links in the UI, it will invalidate any existing Anyone links immediately.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is no way to control those links with IP addresses?

Comment: sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I understand them not being intended being controlled, but I'm searching for some kind of workaround

Comment: The workaround is to disable Anyone links. Anyone links are designed to be fully anonymous with no controls available (sans link expiration).